# Order of operations in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

I completely changed the way my crafting table works and I've run into a problem. The way it works now is it displays all the item in the crafting list. If you can't make the item, the item texture in the table is translucent.

My problem is that when I am checking if the item can be crafted, I am setting a bool variable CanCraft to true or false and it is not setting correctly.

```
 public void CheckForAvailableCrafts(Player player)
    {
        foreach (ItemRecipe recipe in CraftingList)
        {
            if (recipe.CheckForItemsNeeded(player) != null)
            {
                Output = recipe.Output;
                UpdateTable(Output);
            }
            else if (recipe.CheckForItemsNeeded(player) == null)
            {
                Output = new Item();
                Output.ItemName = "empty";
                UpdateTable(Output);
            }
```

The CheckForItemsNeeded method works correctly because it worked fine before I rewrote this part of code. If I have a certain amount of items for the recipe CanCraft for the item is true. The problem lies within the UpdateTable method.

```
            private void UpdateTable(Item output)
    {
        foreach (Item item in CraftingTableItems)
        {
            if (output.ItemName == item.ItemName)
            {
                item.CanCraft = true;
                if (output.ItemName == "empty")
                {
                    item.CanCraft = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My CraftingTableItems is a list of 12 items, and each item is set to a recipe in my CraftingList. So I have 6 items in the CraftingTable that aren't empty.

After I've crafted the item, the item in the table should return to a false value, but it doesn't. Is the order of operations in my for loop correct?

Comment: Take debugger and debug your code step by step

Comment: can `output.ItemName == item.ItemName` & `output.ItemName == "empty"` be true at the same time?

Comment: Yeah. If I am unable to craft an object I return an empty item

Comment: It's hard to say what's going on from here. Have you tried stepping through the code and watching what's happening? You might get some clues that way.

Comment: I have a string displayed above the item which shows its CanCraft value. So when it is set to true and I create it, it will delete the items it used from my inventory but CanCraft will still be equal to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is the `Output` variable. It's not defined as part of the method, and therefore could be modified by other code from another thread. You could change the code to make that variable local to the method (general rule of thumb: always use the smallest scope possible for a variable) or even eliminate it entirely, but I'd re-write the whole thing like this:

```
public void CheckForAvailableCrafts(Player player)
{
    //names of items the player can craft
    var names = CraftingList.Where(r => r.CheckForItemsNeeded(player) != null)
                            .Select(r => r.Output.ItemName);

    //Item objects that player can craft
    var items = CraftingTableItems.Join(names, i => i.ItemName, n => n, (i, n) => i);

    //Set all to false (base state)
    foreach (var item in CraftingTableItems) {item.CanCraft = false;}
    //Set items player can craft back to true
    foreach(var item in items) {item.CanCraft = true;}
}
```

Not only is that less code, but it should be *much* more efficient, as the prior code had to check every CraftingList entry for every possible item the player could craft... O(n<sup>2</sup>), while this is (I think) O(n Log n), maybe even close to O(n).

Yes, that `.Join()` call looks like greek if you're not used to lambda expressions, but it's really not that hard, and again: it greatly simplifies and speeds your code. You can simplify this further if you have an [EqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms132151.aspx) class the compares two items based on the name, or if your `Item` type implements [`IEquatable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms131187.aspx) to compare on ItemNames (and you may find that useful anyway). Assuming the latter, where Item correctly implements IEquatable, your code would look like this:

```
public void CheckForAvailableCrafts(Player player)
{
    //items the player can craft
    var craftableItems = CraftingList.Where(r => r.CheckForItemsNeeded(player) != null)
                                     .Select(r => r.Output);

    //Items objects from the CraftingTable that the player can craft
    craftableItems = CraftingTableItems.Intersect(craftableItems);

    //Set all to false (base state)
    foreach (var item in CraftingTableItems) {item.CanCraft = false;}
    //Set items player can craft back to true
    foreach(var item in craftableItems) {item.CanCraft = true;}
}
```

If you can't spot the difference at first, the first statement saves a step in the Select projection, and the second statement changes from the ugly `Join()` function to the easier-to-read `Intersect()`

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark here, but I would do the following check in case someone has *named* something slightly different:

```
output.ItemName.ToLower() == item.ItemName.ToLower()
```

Comment: I always use lower case when I name things I have to compare :P but I fixed it by changing the CanCraft variable to my recipe instead of output item

Comment: Personally I always dislike seeing `ToLower()` comparisons. Doing `String.Equals(output.ItemName, item.ItemName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` is faster and I think it conveys that you are doing a deliberate case insensitive comparison better.